# How to get a PHAsset of the video from a video URL?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, phasset

How do I get a **PHAsset of a captured video**, if **I've got only a video URL**? My problem is that I know how to get URL of a video from PHAsset, but don't understand how to get PHAsset from video URL.

This is what I tried to do, but it didn't work. It's not for a video, but for a photo...So Idk how to make it for a video.

```
let imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: (NSURL(string: "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0043.JPG"))!)
let image = UIImage(data: imgData!)
```

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: @quant yes, I've already edited the question...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in code to the question...

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: uurl)
    let assetPlaceholder = assetChangeRequest!.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection)
}, completionHandler: nil)
```